# When did the 6/4 chord become more commonplace and acceptable?

Tags: chords, history

In the baroque and classical period, 6/4 chords were only voice leading chords, almost exclusively used as passing chords or auxiliary chords. But even as early as Mendelssohn, we see 6/4 chords performing real functions, and there were even some composers who ended pieces on 6/4 chords!(See Chopin sonata no.2, some editions don't have the pedal that turns it into a 5/3 chord) As the romantic period progressed, the 6/4 chord became more and more commonplace, even when tonality was still central to music. How did this development occur, from the strictly controlled 6/4 chords of the common practice period to it essentially being treated the same way as 5/3 and 6/3 triads?

Comment: According to Glen Haydon's book "The Evolution of the Six-Four Chord.." six-four chords have been used at least since the 13th Century. Earlier notation may not always be precise enough to determine whether a simultaneous occurrence of notes represented a six-four chord. The book goes up through the time of Monteverdi and the English Madrigalists.

Comment: As I was reading your title, my knee-jerk reaction was "it started around Mendelssohn," which you then mention in the post proper. I'm not sure there's a good explanation of its occurrence other than composers just deciding that prior limitations were no longer necessary.

Comment: Beethoven starts the 2nd movement of his Symphony No. 7 with a i6/4 chord (Am/E in this case). He then switches straight to regular i chords (Am in this case). Is this not a 6/4 chord performing a real function and not just being an auxiliary chord?

Comment: @Dekkadeci Sort of, but it's more of an arpeggiation of the Am chord than an independent function. An arpeggiation of the chord is a type of auxiliary chord, I think.